# The effect of the inner diameter of a tube on the speed of a magnet falling through it

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

I have done the experiment of dropping permanent magnets through copper tubes and observing how they fall slower. With a tube that has an inner diameter close to the permanent magnet (a tight fit) the magnet drops very slow. However, with a tube that has an inner diameter a lot larger, the effect is barely seen and the magnet drops faster.

However, in Faraday's Law:

$V=N\frac{\Delta |BA|}{\Delta t}$

The induced voltage should be larger with a larger change in area. Then shouldn't the magnet theoretically fall slower through the tube with the larger diameter?

**Here is my reasoning:**

If the change in magnetic field and number of 'turns' in both tubes are the same, and the area stays constant:

$V_{Large  Diameter}=N\frac{\Delta |B| A_{large}}{\Delta t}$

$V_{Small  Diameter}=N\frac{\Delta |B| A_{small}}{\Delta t}$

and $A_{small}<A_{large}$

then $V_{Small  Diameter} < V_{Large  Diameter}$

and so the current generated by the smaller diameter tube should be less, creating less magnetic field and less opposing force than the larger diameter tube. Then why doesn't the magnet fall faster in the smaller diameter tube in real life?

Answer (score 0):

B*A is only for a constant B on all of A. In general it is

$ \int B\, dA $ . When it is the same magnet then the value will not increase. If there is space between the magnet and the wall then field lines will close within the tube and thus add positive and negative terms and thus the overall magenetic flux that the tube sees will quickly get smaller as the diameter of the tube gets bigger.